# What are some better ways to create Topic Hubs automatically

Tags: facebook, api, web-scraping, wikipedia, freebase

I wish to create something similar for my app like:

- http://www.facebook.com/pages/English-Language/106059522759137
- http://www.freebase.com/view/en/barack_obama

I could make use of Freebase data or Wikipedia data or any other data but I am totally clueless about how to get started and make use of available database dumps in php and mysql.

Please suggest some better ways to create Topic Hubs automatically.

**Update:**

I've decided to download Freebase WEX and it gives me freebase guid/mid for each topic. I wish to make use of these ids to fetch entire topic hub info through freebase API but I couldn't find a way to do that, any suggestions? examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a website with topic pages you should consider the following tasks:

1. Decide which topics your site will cover and which important relationships between those topics you wish to model.
2. [Reconcile those topics](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Data_linkage_guidelines) against external datasets like Freebase and Wikipedia.
3. Decide which data you want to store locally in your database and which data needs to be pulled in dynamically from external sources like APIs. You should have some data stored locally which is specific to your site, otherwise your pages will look like Spam.
4. Create a URL naming scheme for your topic pages.
5. Create HTML templates for your topic pages including Schema.org/RDFa markup so that your topics show up with rich snippets in search.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I've decided to download Freebase WEX and it gives me freebase guid/mid for each topic. I wish to make use of these ids to fetch entire topic info through freebase API but I couldn't find a way to do that, any suggestions?

Comment: Have you seen the Topic API? http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Topic_API